# Concatenate "Description" cells in excel if same transaction recognized

Tags: excel, merge, excel-formula, concatenation, vba

I extracted data from txt files and I was able to make all my columns match, however the "Description" cell was divided into 2 or sometimes 3 cells in rows below for what should be one item. Is there a way to combine those into one "Description" cell?

**Thanks for the help!**

[Example of issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqMZH.jpg)

Comment: Remove Duplicates?

Comment: When you extract the data from the TXT file, the value separator you use is a space, or perhaps space OR comma. If your text file is comma separated you can select only the comma as value separator, which would cause Excel's `Text To Column` function to put your entire descriptions into one cell.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are there is a delimiter (comma, semicolon, etc) in the transaction descriptions, or you are importing fixed width.  Use the "From Text" button on the data tab and choose your text file, make sure you are using appropriate delimiter and text qualifiers.